# parse xml in an iframe

Tags: javascript, ajax, iframe, rss, prototypejs

I want to be able access an rss feed from js.  I have the ability to configure both servers to use the same domain (but different subdomains - eg static.benanderson.us and tech.benanderson.us).  I was hoping I could use the  document.domain property to get around the xss issue.  Here's a snippet http://static.benanderson.us/example.js (not actually live):

```
document.domain = 'benanderson.us';
new Ajax.Request('http://tech.benanderson.us/feeds/posts/default', { \\error
```

However, that doesn't work.  I couldn't find out if document.domain works for xhr requests, so I bagged that and switched to an iframe solution because I've done something similar in the past.

```
$('my_iframe').src='http://tech.benanderson.us/feeds/posts/default';
Event.observe($('my_iframe'), 'load', function() {
  try {
    log(this.contentDocument);  //this displays just fine
    var entries = this.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName('entry');  //error
```

The weird thing is that I can view this.contentDocument in firebug, however it's the getElementsByTagName that errors with a "permission denied..." message.

Any thoughts on how to get either of these solutions to work would be awesome.  I know I could do a proxy - that's not what I'm interested in.

Comment: Hi, did you try to work with the same domain and subdomain?

Comment: not in the xhr attempt because that I won't be able to do that in production.

yes, I did try it in iframe attempt.  That's why I think I've gotten to the root of the problem.  I think perhaps I'm just coding incorrectly.  There's no reason I shouldn't be able to access xml in another frame, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

apparently there is no way to do exactly this.  Howver, I was able to come up with a decent solution.  The rss xml is coming from blogger (tech.benanderson.us).  So I added a javascript function there that could make the xhr to the rss.  Then this javascript sets it's document.domain to benanderson.us and makes a callback.  To sum up:

http://static.benanderson.us/example.js:

```
Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {
  document.domain = 'benanderson.us';
  $('my_iframe').src='http://tech.benanderson.us/2001/01/js.html';
});
function renderFeed(feedXml) {
  ...
```

http://tech.benanderson.us/2001/01/js.html:

```
var url = 'http://tech.benanderson.us/feeds/posts/default';
new Ajax.Request(url, {
  method: 'get',
  onSuccess: function(response) {
    document.domain = 'benanderson.us';
    top.renderFeed(response.responseXML);
  }
});
```

Comment: I'm a tad annoyed now. How is this any different from my solution?

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't speak to the JS technicalities at all, but as a workaround, you could set up a server-side script on the same subdomain that just fetches what you need from the other subdomain.

Comment: +1. @andersonbd1 Is there a reason you can't use a server-side proxy on static.benanderson.us to retrieve the feed?

Comment: yes, I can only use static html, js, and css.  I can't use scripts.  I clearly stated this in the question.

Comment: I see the part about the proxy now, but a fetch script is not exactly the same thing.  Anyway, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

You cant do that, it is not allowed by same origin policy

You can only set document.domain to the superdomain of the current domain, you do that but the same origin policy has to match the whole domain name that it is allowed (tech.benanderson.us != benanderson.us)

Comment: can't do what specifically?

In the iframe example, it works if the iframe contains html.  a document can access (via js) html in its inner iframe even if subdomains are different (using document.domain).

Comment: in which browser? it should not work (and does not in ff and opera)

Comment: any browser.  people do it all the time (I just tried it and it works).  I think I may have found the issue.  You have to set document.domain explicitly in both the containing page AND the inner iframe.  Since this is done in javascript, I fear I may be out of luck if I'm returning xml.

Comment: of course it works if you set both, I was talking about your use case

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that document.domain needs to be set to benanderson.us both on the page loading the iframe and the page in the iframe. That gets a bit stupid in this case since you can't just put javascript into a rss feed, so you'll probably have to make some kind of gateway page on the same subdomain to load that page in a frame for you. Here's a lazy example of that:

```
<html>
<frameset onload="document.domain='benanderson.us';window.frames['content_frame'].location=location.href.split('?request=')[1]">
<frame name=content_frame onload="window.frames['content_frame'].document.domain='benanderson.us'">
</frameset>
</html>
```

So, assuming we call this "gateway.html" and you put this someplace inside the tech.benanderson.us subdomain, you would go "gateway.html?request=http://tech.benanderson.us/feeds/posts/default" So, in this case, you would have to reference it through window.frames["my_frame"].window.frames["content_frame"] and you should get it.

NOTE: I haven't tested this code.

Comment: ...This constitutes a proxy solution?

Comment: CWS - I misread your solution.  Totally my bad.  Let me know how I can make it up.  I haven't logged in to SO in a while, so it might be too late to rectify.  Perhaps I can just snoop for your answers and vote them up.  Again - my apologies.

Comment: Haha, don't worry about it. It's fine. ;) It's just points anyhow. All I wanted was some clarification on it. Thanks.